# Python not finding elasticsearch package

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I just installed with pip install elasticsearch the right package, but is not being found by my .py script.

I have this right now:

**ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages**

```
README                       pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg          urllib3-1.8.3-py2.7.egg-info virtualenv.py                virtualenv_support
easy-install.pth             urllib3                      virtualenv-1.11.6.dist-info  virtualenv.pyc
```

**ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/**

```
easy-install.pth              elasticsearch-1.0.0.dist-info setuptools-4.0.1-py2.7.egg    sitecustomize.py
elasticsearch                 pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg           setuptools.pth                sitecustomize.pyc
```

Now when I run my script myelastic.py:

```
import sys
print sys.path

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
```

I have this:

```
['/Users/tati/Desktop/python', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python27.zip', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myelastic.py", line 5, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ImportError: No module named elasticsearch
```

It's the first time I work with virtualenv, but I'm not sure how to work around this issue, thanks!

Comment: you mention virtualenv but I can't see a trace of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have called your file the same name as the module:

`File "/Users/tati/Desktop/python/elasticsearch.py"`.

It is shadowing the module name so you are importing from your file not the elasticsearch module. Just rename your `.py` to something other than `elasticsearch.py`.

Comment: I just renamed it, was part of the problem, thanks!, but still the rest, is not finding the library, but thanks!

Comment: are you trying to import from a venv or using the system python?

Comment: mmmmmmm I ran "virtualenv <folder project>", that is using the venv no?

Comment: did you install using pip after you activated your venv?

Comment: *pip install virtualenv
*pip install elasticsearch

Comment: so you activated your venv, then ran `pip install elasticserach`? what error are you getting trying to import?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56486/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-francisco-albert).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Hey Padraic.. I'm facing exactly the same issue. I doubled check the environment as well and elastic search is installed there. Please help!

Note: I tried everything mentioned above.

Comment: pip install elasticsearch
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): elasticsearch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3<2.0,>=1.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding to my .bash_profile :

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: This is Mac OS X specific.

Comment: Yes I was testing on mac but still. I had the issue and it is how I fixed. People, as I did, may be googling the issue and find my point interesting.

Comment: On Ubuntu it's /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages